# What is the default PDF Reader in 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, pdf

Recently I installed Ubuntu Oneiric Ocelot 11.10 on my desktop. It has a built-in PDF reader which I accidentally uninstalled when I removed ghostscript with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get remove ghostscript
```

I have no clue what the name of the PDF reader was, and how to get it back on board. Seems like a really easy question, but couldn't figure it out with Googling only.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ubuntu uses [evince](http://projects.gnome.org/evince/) as the default PDF reader. You can install it

- From the terminal by typing

  ```
  sudo apt-get install evince-gtk
  ```
- From Ubuntu software centre by searching for evince
- By clicking here which points to the exact package in Software Centre:

[image: Install via the software center]

Answer (score 3):

The default PDF Reader in 11.10, is evince, to install it, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo apt-get install evince
```